# my server pauses at no reason until I kill the client

Tags: c, sockets, networking, client, server

when i run both client and server i get this as result:

on server

Server is on

Client: XXX.X.X.X accepted
(that's the point that the program pauses until I type ctrl+C in client)
I try to get in while

I get in while
Client 
AI  Choise:Scissor

AI:Wins ratio 0,Looses ratio 0,Ties ratio 1
I get in while
Client 
AI  Choise:Scissor

AI:Wins ratio 0,Looses ratio 0,Ties ratio 2

on client

```
1)--> Paper
2)--> Scissor
3)--> Rock
4)--> Quit
```

^C

my code:

Server:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 printf("\nServer is on\n");

 int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
 socklen_t clilen;
 int Client_Choice;
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
 int n,Who_Wins;
 int ai_wins=0,ai_looses=0,ties=0,total=0,ai_win_ratio=0,ai_looses_ratio=0,ai_ties_ratio;
 time_t t;
 srand((unsigned) time(&t));                                               

 if (argc < 2) {                                                            
     fprintf(stderr,"\nERROR, no port provided\n");                           
     exit(1);                                                               
 }

 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);                                  

 if (sockfd < 0){                                                           
    error("\nERROR opening socket\n",sockfd);                                         
 }

 bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));                              
 portno = atoi(argv[1]);                                                     
 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;                                             
 serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;                                    
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);                                        


 if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){  
    error("\nERROR on binding\n",sockfd);                                      
 }

 listen(sockfd,5);                                                          
 clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

 newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,&clilen);          


 if (newsockfd < 0){                                                        
      error("\nERROR on accept\n",sockfd);                                     
 }

char *cli_IP = malloc(sizeof(cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr));                    

if (!cli_IP){                                                               
    error("\nCould not allocate memory for conversion.\n",sockfd);           
}

inet_ntop( AF_INET , &cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr , cli_IP , INET_ADDRSTRLEN );

printf("\nClient: %s accepted\n",cli_IP);                                    

printf("I try to get in while");

while(Client_Choice!=4){

    printf("I get in while");

    n= read( newsockfd, &Client_Choice, sizeof(Client_Choice) );        
    if(n < 0) {                                                             
        error("\nERROR reading from socket\n",sockfd);                                                        
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
close(newsockfd);                                                          
close(sockfd);                                                              
return 0;
```

}

client

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int sockfd, portno, n;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
struct hostent *server;

int send;
if (argc < 3) {
   fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
   exit(0);
}

portno = atoi(argv[2]);
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sockfd < 0) {
    error("ERROR opening socket\n");
}

server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

if (server == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
}

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    error("ERROR connecting\n");
}

while(send < 1 ||send > 4){

    printf("\n\t1)--> Paper\n\t2)--> Scissor\n\t3)--> Rock\n\t4)--> Quit\n");
    scanf("%d",&send);
    n = write(sockfd,&send,sizeof(send));

    if (n < 0){ 
     error("ERROR writing to socket\n");
    }    

    n = read(sockfd,&send,sizeof(send));

    if (n == 0){ 
         error("ERROR reading from socket\n");
    }
}
close(sockfd);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your server is blocked waiting the message from the client.  You have not reserved resources for dealing with several clients and only have a single process serving a single client (using the connection socket from **accept(2)**).  That's the reason of it to appear blocking.  In a normal server scenario, a new process is spawned by a **fork(2)** system call to deal with the socket obtained from **accept(2)** while the main process continues to **accept(2)** connections on the socket used for accepting new connections.  As you are dealing with two sockets in server, but not attending the socket descriptor where **accept(2)** connections come in,  it appears to be blocked, but it is actually ready to accept the commands from the active client.  This is what is called a sequential server (it doesn't allow a connection before the first one terminates).

By the way, `send` is uninitialized before use in first `while (send < 1 || send > 4)` sentence so in case you get it casually equal to 2 (for example) you won't get client code into the while at all. This is only a point, probably there will be more.  Why have you used different names for the message type interchanged between server and client?  this makes more difficult to search for errors.